# read email response from outlook using email lib python

Tags: python, email, outlook, imap, imaplib

Hello currently I am using IMAPLIB and EMAIL library of python for reading and get then content sends of different emails, but when I received an email response from outlook, I can not get the content from the email am receive a string like this:

**'PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0i\r\ndGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyIgc3R5bGU9\r\nImRpc3BsYXk6bm9uZTsiPiBQIHttYXJnaW4tdG.......'**

this is the code to get the emails, I am using to authenticate IMAPLIB, the email server was built with this repo: https://github.com/modoboa/modoboa

```
mail.select("inbox")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')

inbox_item_list = data[0].split()
list_emails = []
root_dict = {}
campaigns = []


 for item in inbox_item_list:
    result2, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', item, '(RFC2045)')
    raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    to_= email_message["Delivered-To"]
    from_= email_message['From']
    subject_= email_message['Subject']
    counter = 1
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
            continue
        filename = part.get_filename()
        if not filename:
            ext = 'html'
            filename = 'msg-part-%08d%s' %(counter, ext)
        counter += 1
  
    content_type = part.get_content_type()

    if "plain" in content_type:
        pass
    elif "html" in content_type:
        emails = {}
        html_ = part.get_payload()
        soup_ = BeautifulSoup(html_, "html.parser")
        text = soup_.get_text()
```

text is the variable the saves the content of the email, works with Gmail but currently doesn't works with the email response of outlook.

Comment: I am by no means sure, but the bold text looks like it's encrypted, or at least just base64 encoded. Probably the latter.

Comment: currently, i probe the base64 but don't works, this is a hash complete.
https://pastebin.com/NzHCwJ5f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it was just base64 encoded. Here's the decoded text:

```
b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<style type="text/css" style="display:none;"> P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} </style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir="ltr">\r\n<div style="font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">\r\nCount on me<br>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="appendonsend"></div>\r\n<hr style="display:inline-block;width:98%" tabindex="-1">\r\n<div id="divRplyFwdMsg" dir="ltr"><font face="Calibri, sans-serif" style="font-size:11pt" color="#000000"><b>De:</b> Giraluna Gomez &lt;2344@holbertonschool.com&gt;<br>\r\n<b>Enviado:</b> lunes, 24 de mayo de 2021 4:13 p. m.<br>\r\n<b>Para:</b> Giraluna Gomez &lt;lunagolo@hotmail.com&gt;<br>\r\n<b>Cc:</b> david+2022@zeroclickmail.com &lt;david+2022@zeroclickmail.com&gt;<br>\r\n<b>Asunto:</b> Luna golo.Test 2 from email merge</font>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div dir="ltr">Test 2 to email merge.&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div hspace="streak-pt-mark" style="max-height:1px"><img alt="" style="width:0px; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden" src="https://mailfoogae.appspot.com/t?sender=aMjM0NEBob2xiZXJ0b25zY2hvb2wuY29t&amp;type=zerocontent&amp;guid=9189324e-7d1c-4590-b502-8179902f97de"><font color="#ffffff" size="1">\xe1\x90\xa7</font></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

And here's what I used to decode it:

```
from base64 import b64decode

print(b64decode("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"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just work with mailbox/emails (not read RFC and parse data), try:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools:

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        body = msg.text or msg.html
```

*Regards, author of imap_tools